# Applying function based on multiple conditions to Pandas Column

Tags: pandas

I need to apply a function that will decrement the values in a column if they meet two conditions, but otherwise leave them unchanged.
Columns 
'Days' = dt.dayofyear ranging 1-366 because of leap years.
'Years' = dt.year
Then a bunch of other columns.

I've already removed the leapdays and would like to decrement the values in 'Days' >60 in occurring in leap years which in this case all divide by 4.  I keep running into syntax errors, I'm a beginner.

I've surfed around and am for simplicity sake have been trying to apply lambda functions.  This is a simplified version of what I'm attempting:

```
#'Days' contains dt.daysofyear
#'Dates' contains dt.year
#Edited to fix missed quotations and add axis=1
temps['Days'] = temps.apply(lambda x : x['Days'] - 1 if ((x['Days'] > 60) and (x['Year']%4!=0)) else x['Days'], axis=1)
```

I fixed the syntax, now it's just not doing what it's supposed to, values are not decremented

Comment: One error is you need quotes around Days inside your lambda.

Comment: I have fixed that but am still returning a syntax error

Comment: Are you getting an 'ambiguous' error?

Comment: No, it just tells me invalid syntax :

(File "<ipython-input-41-9b07ab2e449c>", line 6
    temps['Days'] = temps.apply(lambda x : x['Days'] - 1 if ((x > 60) and (x['Year']%4!=0) else x['Days'], axis=1)
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Comment: another error is the word 'and' use '&' instead.

Comment: Why not simply `temps[(temps.Days > 60) & (temps.Year % 4 != 0)]['Days'] -= 1`?

Comment: ^ For that line of code it doesn't work to actually alter the values and I get this warning: 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:7: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
​

Comment: Thanks Scott Boston, I made that change but it's still not working to actually change the code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you want to iterate over rows with `apply` you need to use `axis=1`